# MySQL statement to calculate the number of times a total can fill products of different volumes - modification needed

Tags: mysql

MySQL Statement to calculate how many times a total can be divided into different volumes, starting with largest volume first

I have a MySQL statement that calculates how many times a total (grand_total_s) can fill (times_filled) products with different volumes (volume). The statement should start with the largest volume first, using its residual to determine if the next lower volumes can also be filled. Instead, my statement calculates how many times each volume of the products can be filled and not only which ones starting from high to low can be filled.

To make this clearer, the results should look like this for as specific product:

| menu_item_id | school_id | grand_total_s | volume | times_filled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 2287 | 11004 | 5000 | 2 |
| 12 | 2287 | 11004 | 2500 | 0 |
| 12 | 2287 | 11004 | 1500 | 0 |
| 12 | 2287 | 11004 | 750 | 1 |

Currently, the results are looking like this:

| menu_item_id | school_id | grand_total_s | volume | times_filled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 2287 | 11004 | 5000 | 2 |
| 12 | 2287 | 11004 | 2500 | 4 |
| 12 | 2287 | 11004 | 1500 | 7 |
| 12 | 2287 | 11004 | 750 | 14 |

Here is my statement:

```
SELECT
    fm.menu_item_id,
    sa.school_id,
    mi.product_name,
    SUM( fm.volume_per_s ) AS total_s,
    SUM( fm.volume_per_s ) * sa.enrollment AS grand_total_s,
    miv.volume,
    sa.sp_id,
    FLOOR(( SUM( fm.volume_per_s ) * sa.enrollment ) / miv.volume ) AS times_filled,
CASE
        
        WHEN ( SUM( fm.volume_per_s ) * sa.enrollment ) % miv.volume > 0 
        AND miv.volume = max_volume.volume THEN
            ( SUM( fm.volume_per_s ) * sa.enrollment ) % miv.volume ELSE 0 
            END AS residual 
    FROM
        feeding_menu fm
        INNER JOIN menu_items mi ON fm.menu_item_id = mi.id
        CROSS JOIN sp_allocated_schools sa
        LEFT JOIN menu_item_volumes miv ON mi.id = miv.menu_item_id
        LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            fm.menu_item_id,
            sa.school_id,
            MAX( miv.volume ) AS volume 
        FROM
            feeding_menu fm
            INNER JOIN menu_items mi ON fm.menu_item_id = mi.id
            CROSS JOIN sp_allocated_schools sa
            LEFT JOIN menu_item_volumes miv ON mi.id = miv.menu_item_id 
        WHERE
            sa.`status` = 1 
        GROUP BY
            fm.menu_item_id,
            sa.school_id 
        ) AS max_volume ON fm.menu_item_id = max_volume.menu_item_id 
        AND sa.school_id = max_volume.school_id 
    WHERE
        sa.`status` = 1 
    GROUP BY
        fm.menu_item_id,
        sa.school_id,
        miv.volume 
    ORDER BY
    mi.product_name ASC,
    miv.volume DESC;
```

Comment: Please add also create table with data that produces your result for a [mre]

Comment: Even if this can be done in SQL, I don't think it should. SQL is not for solving algorithmic problems like this. I suggest you use an application.

Comment: In MySQL 8.0 you can use recursive query: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NKg6cWU0).

Answer (score 0):

Since no version has been stated, for the sake of compatibility, I'm doing it in MySQL 5.7 which does not support those convenient window functions. And to perform recursive tasks in 5.7, I find using a stored procedure a way to go. Here I am doing the test using part of the result table as the base table since no clear one has been provided so far. 
This is a base table. I added a few lines to test the robustness of the procedure.

```
create table new_test(menu_item_id int unsigned, school_id int unsigned,grand_total_s int,volume int);
truncate new_test;
insert into new_test values(12,     2287,   11004, 5000),
(12,    2287,   11004, 2500),
(12,    2287,   11004, 1500),
(12,    2287,   11004, 750),
(12,    3357,   22003, 15000),
(12,    3357,   22003, 3500),
(12,    3357,   22003, 1200),
(18,    3357,   99887, 20000),
(18,    3357,   99887, 4500),
(18,    3357,   99887, 300)
;

select * from new_test;
+--------------+-----------+---------------+--------+
| menu_item_id | school_id | grand_total_s | volume |
+--------------+-----------+---------------+--------+
|           12 |      2287 |         11004 |   5000 |
|           12 |      2287 |         11004 |   2500 |
|           12 |      2287 |         11004 |   1500 |
|           12 |      2287 |         11004 |    750 |
|           12 |      3357 |         22003 |  15000 |
|           12 |      3357 |         22003 |   3500 |
|           12 |      3357 |         22003 |   1200 |
|           18 |      3357 |         99887 |  20000 |
|           18 |      3357 |         99887 |   4500 |
|           18 |      3357 |         99887 |    300 |
+--------------+-----------+---------------+--------+
```

Now we create a procedure.

```
delimiter //
drop procedure if exists calc_fills//
create procedure calc_fills ()
begin
declare m_id int;
declare o_m_id int default -1; -- the old menu id is to be matched with the next menu id to find if the menu id changes
declare s_id int;
declare o_s_id int default -1; -- the old schook id works similar to the old menu id
declare g_total int;
declare leftover int; -- leftover is the dividend used to do the MOD and DIV calculation. The result from its MOD calculation makes the new leftover value. 
declare vol int; -- vol is the divisor in MOD and DIV calculation

declare t_filled int; -- result of DIV calculation

declare fin bool default false;

declare c cursor for 
select menu_item_id, school_id, grand_total_s, volume
from new_test
order by menu_item_id, school_id, volume desc; -- make sure we have the correct order before performing the calculation task 

declare continue handler for not found set fin=true;

create temporary table results (menu_item_id int unsigned, school_id int unsigned,grand_total_s int,volume int, times_filled int);


open c;
lp:loop
fetch c into m_id, s_id, g_total, vol ; 

if fin then
leave lp;
end if;

-- changes of either m_id or s_id from the old ones value shall reset the leftover value to the new grand_total value.
if m_id != o_m_id or s_id != o_s_id then
set o_m_id=m_id, o_s_id=s_id, leftover=g_total;
end if;

-- calculation to get the times_filled and the new leftover values
set t_filled=leftover div vol;
set leftover=leftover mod vol;

insert results values (m_id, s_id, g_total, vol, t_filled);

end loop lp;

select * from results; -- No ORDER BY clause is needed here, since without a PK or UNIQUE NOT NULL key, a clustered index is created based on the order of insertion. In this case the sequence stems from the the sequence of the SELECT statement in the cursor, which already has an ORDER BY defined. 
drop temporary table results;
end//

delimiter ;
```

Now we test the procedure;

```
call calc_fills;
+--------------+-----------+---------------+--------+--------------+
| menu_item_id | school_id | grand_total_s | volume | times_filled |
+--------------+-----------+---------------+--------+--------------+
|           12 |      2287 |         11004 |   5000 |            2 |
|           12 |      2287 |         11004 |   2500 |            0 |
|           12 |      2287 |         11004 |   1500 |            0 |
|           12 |      2287 |         11004 |    750 |            1 |
|           12 |      3357 |         22003 |  15000 |            1 |
|           12 |      3357 |         22003 |   3500 |            2 |
|           12 |      3357 |         22003 |   1200 |            0 |
|           18 |      3357 |         99887 |  20000 |            4 |
|           18 |      3357 |         99887 |   4500 |            4 |
|           18 |      3357 |         99887 |    300 |            6 |
+--------------+-----------+---------------+--------+--------------+
```